# Iptables killswitch is blocking .local dns lookups

Tags: iptables, dhcp, wireguard

I have added `! -d 192.168.0.0/16` and `! -d fc00::/7` to Wireguard's killswitch example (see `man wg-quick` EXAMPLES):

```sh
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -d fc00::/7 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```

This lets me access other hosts on my 192.168.X.X network while the VPN is running.  It does however appear to block DNS lookups to domains such as `myhost.local`.  I say this because I can connect to the VPN and still ping `myhost.local`.  After only a few minutes of running the VPN, the ping stops working and reports: `ping: myhost.local: Name or service not known`.  I'm guess the DNS cache expired.

My understanding is that since I did not specify the protocol in iptables (like `-p udp`) it should exclude **all** protocols from the REJECT rule.

I'm able to bring the VPN up without iptables and ip6tables rules and I am always able to resolve `myhost.local`.

Do you think it is still rejecting UDP DNS lookups on some other criteria?  How can I tweak the rule to allow for local DNS lookups?

Answer (score 0):

You've accidentally split your IP4 & IP6 commands - in your example both lines should be part of PostUp with && in between, and you should have a corresponding PreDown to match.  For example:

```
PostUp = iptables -I OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -I OUTPUT ! -d fc00::/7 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
PreDown = iptables -D OUTPUT ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show  %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT && ip6tables -D OUTPUT ! -d fc00::/7 ! -o %i -m mark ! --mark $(wg show  %i fwmark) -m addrtype ! --dst-type LOCAL -j REJECT
```